# Improve VNC connection speed over LAN

Tags: wireless, performance, vnc

I am wondering if there is anyway to increase the performance of a VNC connection. I have an server setup (ubuntu) with a wired connection to the router. Its connected to the house sound system.

I have tried to play movies over the connection so i get good sound quality and can setup my laptop anywhere but its way too low fps (Prob about 10 or 15). Other than buying a faster router or having a wired connection from the laptop to it, is there any software way i can speed up the fps? would increasing the priority on the server make much difference? my guess is no. I think the main bottleneck is the wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your bottle neck is, but IMO FreeNX is the fastest VNC server.